# Migration from Magento Community to Magento Go error

Tags: magento

I'm working on migrating my Magento Community story ver 1.8.1.0 to Magento Go ver 1.1.2.3. I've created all my custom attributes and my attribute sets, and exported my product listing. When I attempt to import it into Magento Go, I get this error:

**Column names:** 
"_root_category", 
"_group_price_website", 
"_group_price_customer_group", 
"_group_price_price", 
"_media_attribute_id", 
"_media_image", 
"_media_lable", 
"_media_position", 
"_media_is_disabled" are invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs into a similar problem, I removed these columns. They are no longer valid columns and everything worked fine.